# Regular Expressions: Find pattern in string

Tags: java, regex, string

Somebody can explain how to use regular expression in java. I have few strings  `3 :- N, ‘V—g'uﬁ “ ‘L Total: 13-70 "0- 1‘ i` and  `r _._A_ ,,1 Total: $13.70 i- T«`. I need to extract Total: with sum after it: Ex of expected output `Total: 13-70, Total: $13.70`. 
I tried to use following code... But as I understand, it will not catch symbols, such as `$.-`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Total: \\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
```

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("Total:\\s*\\$?\\d+(?:[-.]\\d+)?")`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96GvP2/1).

Comment: It will catch those symbols, you just have to escape them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
Total:\s*\$?\d+(?:[-.]\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96GvP2/1).

**Details**

- `Total:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\$?` - an optional `$` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[-.]\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[-.]` - either `-` or `.`
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

[image]

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Total:\\s*\\$?\\d+(?:[-.]\\d+)?");
```

If you need to extract the value use a capturing group round the pattern you need to extract (here, `\$?\d+(?:[-.]\d+)?`, for example) and access the group value like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Total:\\s*(\\$?\\d+(?:[-.]\\d+)?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```